# How to POST integer request to server in swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift, post, nsurlconnection

```
    let theRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    theRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let parameters = ["otp":firstDigit.text!,"otp":secondDigit.text!,"otp":thirdDigit.text!,"otp":fourthDigit.text!] as Dictionary<String,String>
```

How to add parameters to pass numbers in to the server side. There is only one field in the server side and I have to pass 4 integers using four different text fields. How can I pass it? Basically I am passing an OTP(One time password with four digits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make the OTP variable like this:-

```
 var otpText:String= firstDigit.text + secondDigit.text +thirdDigit.text+fourthDigit.text
```

then form the parameter:-

```
let parameters : NSDictionary =["otp":otpText]
```

Comment: What should I do if I have to pass it as string?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the property HTTPBody: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSMutableURLRequest/HTTPBody

Not compiled myself, but would be something like:

```
let otp = firstDigit.text + secondDigit.text+thirdDigit.text+fourthDigit.text
let json = [ "OTP" : otp ]
let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros, error: nil)
theRequest.HTTPBody = jsonData
```

What this code does:

- Concatenate your text values to make a string
- Create a dictionary (JSON object) with the key your server expected
  and the value of the concatenated string
- Convert that dictionary to NSData as expected by the HTTPBody property
- Set the HTTPBody property on your NSMutableURLRequest

Also checkout out https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking. It makes it super simple to handle HTTP requests using iOS.